# how to hide column of GridPanel in extjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

hi i have gridcoumn with multiple columns ,i want hide and show some column with AriaAttributes() when change my combobox(this code is ok just not work hide and show columns)
my code:

```
     @(X.GridPanel()
          .View(X.GridView().GetRowClass(x => x.Fn = "MyRowCls"))
          .Stateful(true)
          .Region(Region.Center)
          .ID("MyGrid")
X.Column().Text("a").DataIndex(Model, m => m.a),
X.Column().Text("b").DataIndex(Model, m => m.b).AriaAttributes(myAttr),//show and hide this column
X.Column().Text("c").DataIndex(Model, m => m.b),
X.Column().Text("c").DataIndex(Model, m => m.b),
X.Column().Text("c").DataIndex(Model, m => m.b).AriaAttributes(myAttr),//show and hide this column
X.Column().Text("a").DataIndex(Model, m => m.a)
...
```

and jquery code is :

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp('MyGrid');
grid.initialConfig.columns.items.forEach(
        ... /checked AriaAttributes is ok
{
        item.Hidden(true); // not work
        //item.setVisible(false)  // not work
        ....  // not work
}
...
   }
```

but not work

Comment: What version of extjs is that?

Comment: ExtJS 6.5.2.463

Comment: please tell me why the methods begin with a capital letter and what @ means

Comment: because that work in ,net views

Comment: never seen extis implementation for .net before)

Comment: never saw usage of Ext like this ))). please see [bindings](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/guides/application_architecture/view_models_data_binding.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call `setVisible` a method on a simple object, because `initialConfig.columns` stores the original configs of columns that did not pass the conversion to `gridcolumns` instance.

The columns themselves are here - `grid.columns` and it has needed methods

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp('MyGrid');
grid.columns.items.forEach(item =>
    ...
    {
        item.setVisible(false);
        // or you can call hide() method
    }
    ...
   });
```